# Does apache or flask need special setting for a web application which use pickle?

Tags: python, apache, flask, pickle, wsgi

In Visual Studio i have realized a web api in python with flask which uses pickle to load an SVM, the overall system has been then deployed on apache.
My problem is that when i try the system debugging from visual studio everything works fine, but when i load it on the apache server the page just load wihtout giving either results or errors.
The code of the web application is reported below:

```
import PythonApplication2 as ml
import requests
import json
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import pickle as pk

MLwebapp = Flask(__name__)

left_model=pk.load(open('C:\\myapp\\app\\left_classifier.pickle','rb'))
right_model=pk.load(open('C:\\myapp\\app\\right_classifier.pickle','rb'))

wsgi_app = MLwebapp.wsgi_app
# Make the WSGI interface available at the top level so wfastcgi can get it.


@MLwebapp.route('/')
def start():
    return render_template('WebPage1.html')

@MLwebapp.route('/test')
def hello():
    number='203'
    list_left=[]
    list_right=[]
    for i in range(0,19):
        data=requests.get('url here'+number+str(i))
        json_data=json.loads(data.json())
        number=json.loads(json_data['Dati'])
        left_temp=[x[1] for x in number]
        right_temp=[z[2] for z in number]
        list_left.append(left_temp)
        list_right.append(right_temp)
    patient_vector_right,patient_vector_left=ml.funzionetotale(list_left,list_right)
    patient_vector_left=patient_vector_left.reshape(1, -1)
    patient_vector_right=patient_vector_right.reshape(1, -1)
    prediction=ml.machine_learning(patient_vector_left,patient_vector_right,left_model,right_model)
    risultato="Risultato: " + prediction
    return jsonify(risultato)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '8080'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 8080
    MLwebapp.run(HOST, PORT)
```

The template WebPage1.html is very simple with just a button for testing the system:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ciao</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test button2</h1>
    <form method="get" action="/test">
        <input type="submit" value="Press for test"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Regarding settings for apache and WSGI:
In httpd.conf:

```
added  
LoadFile "c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/shared/python36_64/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/myapp/flask/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/myapp/flask"  
Removed the # from LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so  
added  
Listen 8080
Removed the # from conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
added  
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin localhost
        ServerName  localhost:8080
        WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/myapp/app/web.wsgi"
        DocumentRoot "C:/myapp/app"
        <Directory "C:/myapp/app">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog "C:/myapp/app/logs/error.log"
        CustomLog "C:/myapp/app/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Created web.wsgi file in the app root with:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/myapp/app')

from app import MLwebapp as application
```

With some tests i've understand that the problem lies in the relation between wsgi and pickle, but i couldn't find a guide or post which could help me resolve my problem.

Comment: What do you see in the logs though?

Comment: Nothing in the error log and "::1 - - [29/Jun/2019:18:01:03 +0200] "-" 408 -" in the access log

Answer (score 1):

One way forward is to rule out pickle being an issue. An easy way to do that is to catch any exception that occurs when trying to load the pickle, and pass those along to your starting template. Something like

```
try:
    left_model=pk.load(open('C:\\myapp\\app\\left_classifier.pickle','rb'))
    left_model_ex = None
except Exception as ex:
    left_model = None
    left_model_ex = repr(ex)
```

(and the same for `right_model`)

pass `left_model_ex` into the template, which do something like

```
{% if left_model_ex %}<div>{{ left_model_ex }}</div>{% endif %}
```

where it'll be visible.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i tried the method you suggesed and i noticed that the system works fine once at random, no exception got catched. it worked fine (as should works from the origin) after a pc restart, i tried to restart the pc again, but the second time didn't work, seems to work really randomly and this thing is blowing up my mind.
p.s. when the system got stuck i need to restart the apache server or it won't load even the webpage template.

Comment: In a situation like that, I'd suspect memory starvation. What does the process monitor show?

Comment: The process monitor didn't show anything in particular, memory usage of chrome under 5% and memory usage of apache http server 1.2%, but i noticed that the system stop working when i call the http from a new tab of google chrome, if i just stay on the same tab the system works fine at every call, could this be the problem that i confused for randomness?

Comment: EDIT delete the last part of my last comment, a new series of test showed that the not working is still random.

Comment: Is there any chance that you're in a situation where two requests for `/test` are being handled in parallel, and `ml.funzionetotale` mutates global variables?

Comment: I don't think i am in the situation you supposed, but i find a really weird thing: given that on "not working" situation the access log gave a 408 error i made a little research about the cited error and apache server, i found some guides talking about KeepAlive setting which is totally missing in my httpd.conf! i tried to add this settings in the root section of http.conf, but doesn't work and can't find a situation like mine.

Comment: i FINALLY made it works, i will write everything just in case someone will have my same issue: the configuration for KeepAlive is in a file called httpd-default.conf in a folder called "extra", but needs to be included in the httpd.conf file, here i modified the settings turning on KeepAlive, MaxKeepAliveRequests 500, KeepAliveTimeout 2, UseCanonicalName Off.
Anyway the most important change i made, according to my opinion, was to add WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} in the application directory tab in httpd-vhost.conf. I still owe my gratitude sir for pushing me on these researchs.